# Type definition for a react/jsx element that accepts a specific set of props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

If I have the following:

```
interface TestProps { test: string }
const TestComponent = (props: TestProps) => <>{props.test}</>;

interface OtherProps { test2: number }
const OtherComponent = (props: OtherProps) => <>{props.test2}</>;
```

How can I ensure that a variable is a JSX element derived from `TestComponent`, but **not** `OtherComponent`?

E.g. the following should work fine:

```
const testElement: ReactElement<TestProps> = <TestComponent test="hi"/>; // OK
```

But this should not work:

```
const testElement: ReactElement<TestProps> = <OtherComponent test2={6}/>; // Warning
```

Help greatly appreciated

Comment: You can't do that 
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsx.html#the-jsx-result-type, 
"*it is not possible to retrieve type information about the element, attributes or children of the JSX from this interface (JSX.Element). It is a black box.*". The most you can do is change `JSX.Element`, but it will still be the same for all jsx elements you create. You will have to wrap it in a kind of interface or something, or use `React.createElement` instead and disallow the use of `JSX.Element`